# How to remove 'crosshairs' from a Floating Action Button?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have added 3 FABs under a relative layout and now i am facing this issue as shown in the image attached, where i am getting crosshairs across FAB. 
Can you please sugest how can I remove it? [image]

Comment: if your using an imag as background for you buttons i'd assume they are [9patch images](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) but with an invalid name (the should end with `.9.png`) so that they are not recognized. and the "crosshair" are the points to show where the image can strecht. OR you are using `.9.png`but used Photoshop or similar to change the color without taking care that thos dots remain pure black to be recognized.

Comment: I m using setBackgroundTint()  from the code behind to set the color. Not using  any 9 patch images

Comment: but you are using an image? have you checked if there are any hints for the "crosshair"?

Comment: I am not using any image, I already confirmed. And this issue does not appear when I add the buttons along with viewpager in a relative layout. But, if i add them in a separate layout, crosshairs are visible.

Comment: then I'm sorry... I had a similar issue one when having a broken 9 patch. never used fab. good luck! :(

Comment: You should specify the kind of FAB you used since there are countless libraries out there any mabye provide some code where you set the background and how